# How to return values of a tuple in a variable (varchar) using sql server

Tags: sql-server

'm Staff with a problem where I need to grab the values ​​that are within the INSERTED or DELETED table a trigger using sql server. The problem: How to get these values ​​all at once and throws them into a variable of type varchar for example. I'm doing a log scheme for data recovery in the bank and needed that values ​​in a single variable. I know the INSERTED and DELETED tables feature a single tuple that contains the data you need, which are the values ​​of the fields, just not sure how I would do to get these values​​.

example of how we wanted it to be stored in the output variable: '1; MyName; Age '

Ie, the field values ​​of the INSERTED table eg concatenated and separated by ';'

Comment: First Declare a temp table then Use Inserted or Deleted to fill it. Then by some query make what you want. If tell me how the variable must be I can help by query.

Comment: Do you realise that the INSERTED or DELETED table can have *many* rows? Would you really like to store all of them in a single `varchar` variable?

Comment: in fact they will have a single tuple because I'm doing my queries within a trigger that captures events of type insert, delete and update. a single tuple will contain the values ​​of the query made ​​by the user (insert, delete or update)

Comment: Meysam Tolouee. 
Well, I wanted a variable of type varchar and the query values ​​stored within the User would be as follows: if the User fisesse the following query 
insert into Person (name, age) values ​​('Leandro', 20), al my variable inside the trigger that would treat this insert would look like in the end: @ MyVariable = 'Leandro; 20' 

Well I originally thought of doing a select using to get this information and concatenate the variable, but if you have another way or a function for it will be very welcome ^ ^ kkkkkkk

Answer (score 0):

Books Online or MS's Technet will show you how to retrieve the values from INSERTED and DELETED and populate a temporary table.  Then you can `SELECT` from your temporary table, convert each column to `varchar` and concatenate with your chosen delimiter.

This is going to affect performance, however.  It would be better if your application wrote the business transaction's data to a log file before calling SQL Server rather than pass it back afterwards.  This would keep the extra load off the DB server and actually protect you against a wider range of failure modes.

Note that it is possible to configure a SQL Server instance for disaster recovery with no data loss.  Then you wouldn't have to do this at all.